# Deleting dataFrame row in Pandas if a combination of column values equals a tuple in a list

Tags: python, pandas

I currently do this to delete a row that has a specific column `'some_column'` value that is found in a list `removal_list`

```
df = df[~df['some_column'].isin(removal_list)]
```

How can I do this if I want to compare a combination of values in say a list of tuples ?  (doesn't necessarily need to be a list of tuples if there is a better way to achieve this)

for example:

```
removal_list = [(item1,store1),(item2,store1),(item2,store2)]
```

if `df['column_1']` and `df['column_2']` of a specific row have values `item1` and `store1` (or any other tuple in `removal_list`), then delete that row

also, it might be that there are more than two columns that need to be assessed

**EDIT**
better example:

```
client  account_type    description
0   1   2   photographer
1   2   2   banker
2   3   3   banker
3   4   2   journalist
4   5   4   journalist
```

`remove_list = [(2,journalist),(3,banker)]`

check on columns `account_type` and `description`

Output:

```
client  account_type    description
0   1   2   photographer
1   2   2   banker
4   5   4   journalist
```

Comment: Can you add data sample and expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say you have

```
removal_list = [(item1,store1),(item2,store1),(item2,store2)]
```

Then

```
df[['column_1', 'column_2']].apply(tuple, axis=1)
```

should create a Series of tuples, and so

```
df[['column_1', 'column_2']].apply(tuple, axis=1).isin(removal_list)
```

is the binary condition you're after. Removal is the same as you did before. This should work for any number of columns.

**Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]})
>>> df[['a', 'b']].apply(tuple, axis=1).isin([(1, 3), (30, 40)])
0    (1, 3)
1    (2, 4)
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest create `DataFrame` and [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with default inner join:

```
remove_list = [(2,'journalist'),(3,'banker')]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(remove_list, columns=['account_type','description'])
print (df1)
   account_type description
0             2  journalist
1             3      banker

df = df.merge(df1, how='outer', indicator=True).query('_merge != "both"').drop('_merge', 1)
print (df)
   client  account_type   description
0       1             2  photographer
1       2             2        banker
4       5             4    journalist
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to create a series from zipping 2 columns, then use Boolean indexing. I also advise you use `set` instead of `list` for O(1) lookup.

```
remove_set = {(2,'journalist'),(3,'banker')}

condition = pd.Series(list(zip(df.account_type, df.description))).isin(remove_set)

res = df[~condition]

print(res)

   client  account_type   description
0       1             2  photographer
1       2             2        banker
4       5             4    journalist
```

Answer (score 2):

If the index was set to be `['account_type', 'description']`, we could use the `drop` method.

```
df.set_index(['account_type', 'description']).drop(remove_list).reset_index()

   account_type   description  client
0             2  photographer       1
1             2        banker       2
2             4    journalist       5
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the query method with an extra column to select against.

```
removal_list = [(item1,store1),(item2,store1),(item2,store2)]

df['removal_column'] = df.apply(lambda x: (x.account_type, x.description), axis='columns')
df = df.query('removal_column not in @removal_list').drop('removal_column', axis='columns')
```